# Android- ConcurrentModificationException when sync data with Amplify

Tags: android, kotlin, aws-amplify

I have this general variable called `pendingStates` where I am store the current state with a timestamp

```
private val pendingStates =  mutableListOf<Pair<String, String>>() 

fun saveState(state: String){
        val now = TimeUtil.getFractionalExactTime()
        pendingStates.add(Pair(now,state))
        savePeriod()
    }

 private suspend fun savePendingStates() {
        val statesToSave = pendingStates.toList()
        pendingStates.clear()
        statesToSave.forEach { state ->
            saveToAWS(
                DeviceState.Builder()
                    .time(state.first)
                    .state(state.second)
                    .trackerperiodId(pid)
                    .id(getStateID(state.second, state.first))
                    .build()
            )
        }

        delay(DELAY_BETWEEN_MODELS_MS)
    }
```

saveToAWS method

```
private suspend fun <T : Model> saveToAWS(obj: T, delayMs: Long = DELAY_BETWEEN_MODELS_MS) {
        AWS.save(obj) {}
        delay(delayMs)
    }
```

AWS.save method

```
fun save(model: Model, onComplete:(res:Response) -> Unit){
        Amplify.DataStore.save(model,
            {
                onComplete(Response(true,it.item(),null))
            },
            {
                it.localizedMessage?.let { it1 -> onComplete(Response(false,null,it1)) }
                amplifyRetry()
            }
        )

    }
```

but I got this error

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException:
       at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:860)
       at com.example.sleeptracker.models.SleepPeriod.savePendingStates(SleepPeriod.kt:448)
       at com.example.sleeptracker.models.SleepPeriod.access$savePendingStates(SleepPeriod.kt:21)
       at com.example.sleeptracker.models.SleepPeriod$savePendingStates$1.invokeSuspend(:14)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

I have tried many things but after couple days I got the same error

1- use an iterator to be like this
statesToSave.iterator().forEach { state ->

2- copy existing list to a new list then clear it

```
val statesToSave = pendingStates.toList()
        pendingStates.clear()
```

3- remove item by item

val statesToSave = pendingStates.toList()

```
    statesToSave.forEach { state ->
        saveToAWS(
            DeviceState.Builder()
                .time(state.first)
                .state(state.second)
                .trackerperiodId(pid)
                .id(getStateID(state.second, state.first))
                .build()
        )
     pendingStates.remove(state)
    }
```

but still all throw error from time to time I need a solid solution